# NSString method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: not trimming comma

Tags: ios, nsstring, nscharacterset

I have the following code for removing extra characters from some strings representing numbers:

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToKeep = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSCharacterSet *charactersToBeRemoved = [charactersToKeep invertedSet];

NSString *myString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
myString = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charactersToBeRemoved];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

After the method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`, all the extra characters but the comma are removed. After the call to `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:` the comma is removed. Why isn't it removed after the first call?

Here is a sample of what myString looks like after each line of code:

```
myString = " $9,959 "
myString = "9,959"
myString = "9959"
```

I also tried

```
NSCharacterSet *charactersToBeRemoved = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
```

and got the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: only trims characters from the ends of the string, not on the inside.